# Node.js log4j-like logging system

Tags: node.js, logging, log4j

Could you recommend me a good log4j-like logging system for node.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a log4j port, but Winston offers some similar functionality. https://github.com/indexzero/winston

Answer (score 10):

I think Winston is really good, however since you mentioned log4j you might be interested in the node port: [node-log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node)

Answer (score 2):

**LIGHEWEIGHT SOLUTION**

I have looked through many loggers, and I wasn't able to find a lightweight solution - so I decided to make a simple solution that is posted on github.

- Saves the file
- Gives you a pretty output (we all love that)
- Easy to use

I hope this helps you out.

**SETUP**

```
https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js
```

*PS: If there are any problems, I would appreciate it if you can fix it and then do a pull request. Otherwise, you are more than welcome to post as an issue.*

Answer (score 1):

You can also try looking at https://www.npmjs.org/package/bunyan

Its output is JSON format and can have different stream for output like stoud, log file along with option to number of files to maintain before rotate/recycle similar to Log4j.

As per the documentation on npm, it is also used by Joyent in the production.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with log4js-node (or just log4js for short). I was even able to use watchr to stalk (watch) the log4js configuration file, and set logging levels without rebooting my .js code in my angular middleware. One tricky suggestion that isn't obvious in the docs, here is how you can handle the call back for the shutdown/reboot for hot conf changes within the 'update' switch from the watchr listener.

```
console.log('shutting down log4js');
log4js.shutdown((err) => {
     if (err!=undefined) {
          console.log('shutting down log4js msg: ' + err);
     }
});
console.log('rebooting log4js');
log4js.configure('./myconfigfile.json');
logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

To all do not use "log4j" library. Use the original one which is log4js.
log4j is a duplicate of the original and it`s a hacked mode.

For more information check those articles:
https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2021/dec/10/software-flaw-most-critical-vulnerability-log-4-shell

https://www.esecurityplanet.com/threats/apache-log4j-zero-day-puts-servers-at-risk/

https://www.huntress.com/blog/rapid-response-critical-rce-vulnerability-is-affecting-java

Comment: FWIW, the original was log4j and log4js is a port. Also, it has since been fixed.